# Save Screen Layout in Flight Simulator X (FSX Steam) with 2 screens

Tags: monitor, windows-8.1, flight-simulator-x

I would like to put Flight Simulator X displaying the cockpit gauges and controls on my laptop 15" touchscreen, and put FSX displaying the outside view on my 32" HDMI TV (like the TV is the windshield of the airplane).
I already achieved that, but every time I play free flight, I have to move and arrange the windows (move the outside view to the 2nd screen (TV) and resize the cockpit to full screen of my laptop screen)

**How do I save the "layout" of screens so I never have to move and arrange the cockpit anymore?**

I am using the Steam version of the Microsoft Flight Simulator X on a Windows 8.1 OS.